# Cannot Upgrade Xcode 11 to Xcode 11.1

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

I'm unable to upgrade Xcode 11GM to 11.1 for some time on my Mid 2014 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina. I've installed Xcode from Mac AppStore ages ago (IIRC circa 2014), and upgraded step by step since then. Currently, I'm experiencing the following loop:

1. AppStore reports that I have an update.
2. I open AppStore, open updates, click "Update" on Xcode.
3. Mac Downloads ~2.5GB first.
4. Installs that patch.
5. Continues to get the full package (~7.6GB).
6. It starts to install.
7. After some churning and install, it reports "Cannot download Xcode now, please try again later."

I have more than enough space on the disk, and nothing is modified in Xcode or in the OS (no homebrew or something similar).

Did anyone experience something similar? Are there solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try to drag it to the trash. You might have to purge some Xcode files in `~/Library` because the App Store thought it was still installed. This worked for me.

Comment: I've purged XCode completely and reinstalling it now. It started to get the full package directly. Will update the question as soon as the results come in.

Comment: @bayindirh ok, hope it works

Comment: This works. The error in the install log is ironic / funny isn't it? '/var/log/install.log and saw this:

 

PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=501 "The package is attempting to install content to the system volume." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package is attempting to install content to the system volume.} {

            NSLocalizedDescription = "The package is attempting to install content to the system volume.";' - Yes, Apple, SIP is a thing ;-)

Answer (score 8):

As per [Xcode 11.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_1_release_notes), it is a known issue when trying to update to Xcode 11.1. To solve the issue, use the suggested workaround -- delete the existing Xcode.app or temporarily change the Xcode.app file extension.

> **Known Issues**
>
> Xcode may fail to update from the Mac App Store after updating to macOS Catalina. (56061273)
>
> **Workaround**: *To trigger a new download you can **delete the existing Xcode.app or temporarily change the file extension*** so it is no longer visible to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks Apple for making things easy for us. I guess a lot of people (including me) are really happy for having to do a full reinstall of Xcode which include a few side effects like having no access to the command line developer tools in the meantime. Who needs basic stuff like git running full time on their MacBooks?